# Get a result when an option value selection is changed in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to get a different value when the value of an option is changed. I have this code, but when I change my selection, the result is not changing.

```js
let cantidad1 = document.getElementById("cantidad");
let moneda1 = document.getElementById("cambio").value;
if (moneda1 === "cup") {
    tipodemoneda = 97;
} else if (moneda1 === "mlc") {
    tipodemoneda = 0.89;
}
let tasadecambio = tipodemoneda;
let resultado1 = document.getElementById("resultado")

cantidad1.addEventListener("change", () => {
    resultado1.value = parseFloat(tasadecambio) * parseFloat(cantidad1.value)
})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listen for `input` events instead of change events. Change events only fire for a text input or text area when the the element lose focus [(1)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event)

```js
let cantidad1 = document.getElementById("cantidad");
let moneda1 = document.getElementById("cambio").value;
if (moneda1 === "cup") {
  tipodemoneda = 97;
} else if (moneda1 === "mlc") {
  tipodemoneda = 0.89;
}
let tasadecambio = tipodemoneda;
let resultado1 = document.getElementById("resultado")

cantidad1.addEventListener("input", () => {
  resultado1.value = parseFloat(tasadecambio) * parseFloat(cantidad1.value)
})
```

```html
<input id="cantidad">
<input id="cambio" value="cup">
<input id="resultado">
```

Also the way the code is right now, `moneda1` only gets set once. You should move it into the event handler.

```js
let cantidad1 = document.getElementById("cantidad");
let moneda1 = document.getElementById("cambio");
let resultado1 = document.getElementById("resultado")
let tipodemoneda; // Put this to stop it from being a global variable (window.tipodemoneda)

function updateResultado() { // Handler in its own function
if (moneda1.value === "cup") { // Check mondedal.value since it can change
    tipodemoneda = 97;
  } else if (moneda1.value === "mlc") {
    tipodemoneda = 0.89;
  }
  let tasadecambio = tipodemoneda;
  resultado1.value = parseFloat(tasadecambio) * parseFloat(cantidad1.value)
}

cantidad1.addEventListener("input", updateResultado)
moneda1.addEventListener("change", updateResultado)
```

```html
<input id="cantidad">
<select id="cambio">
  <option value="mlc">mlc</option>
  <option value="cup">cup</option>
</select>
<input id="resultado">
```